# Trying to generate a Keras model with my own data instead of cifar10

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I have followed this example:
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/10/30/how-to-multi-gpu-training-with-keras-python-and-deep-learning/

and had an issue with the following line(line #51):

```
((trainX, trainY), (testX, testY)) = cifar10.load_data()
```

as i would like to train it on my own data
is there any simple way to generate this kind of output without digging deep into cifar's implementation?
I am pretty sure it is something that people already did but i cannot find a sample/tutorial/example

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you have your images as .jpg format, and your labels as csv format called `label.csv`, and separated them into 2 folders, `train folder` and `test folder`.

Then you can do the following to get the `x_train`

```
import cv2 #library for reading images
import numpy as np
import glob #library for reading files in a folder
x_train= []
for file in glob.glob("train/*.jpg"):
    im = cv2.imread(file) #reading each image from the folder
    x_train.append(im)
x_train = np.array(x_train)
```

And you can do the following to get the `y_train`

```
import csv
y_train= []
with open('train/label.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        y_train.append([int(row[0])]) #converting the string to int (otherwise the csv data will be read as string)
y_train = np.array(y_train)
```

You can do the same for your test folder, just change the name of the parameters and arguments.